# magento event not fireing with graphql

Tags: magento2, event-observer, graphql

i create a custom module in  Magento 2.4 .
I create an observer on the event "customer_register_success" . when i use graphql(i use pwa in frontend) the event is not firing but it work normally when i use the default magento frontend.any help please.thx

Answer (score 3):

**#1 First Solution**

Well as I looked it up, the event `customer_register_success` executes only when the form submits to the url  `customer/account/createpost` here is the controller`\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost`.

To observe the same functionality but for the graphql, change your event to `customer_save_after_data_object` which is in the `\Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository` class.

```
            'customer_save_after_data_object',
            [
                'customer_data_object' => $savedCustomer,
                'orig_customer_data_object' => $prevCustomerData,
                'delegate_data' => $delegatedNewOperation ? $delegatedNewOperation->getAdditionalData() : [],
            ]
        );
```

Also if you will go with `customer_save_after_data_object` event remove the old one `(customer_register_success)` because it will be fired twice when someone will create customer from the frontend.

**Also this event fires every time someone saves customer not only when it is registered for the first time, so you need to add some custom logic there.**

**#2 Second Solution**

You can also create an after plugin for this method `\Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement::createAccount` which will be triggered only on the account creation. I believe this solution is better as Magento likes `Plugins` more than the `Observer/Events` pattern. Here is the link for the documentation of plugins [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html)